# How to check which condition having data in Laravel query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I hope to retrieve `type == 'supplier'` if not `type == 'retailer'`. And I hope retrieve `type == 'retailer'` only, if both `type` also have the customer.

Is there a way to combine below query condition become one query?

```
$data = Sale::where('type', 'retailer')->where('customer', 'LIKE', '%peter%')->get();
if (count($data) == 0) {
   $data = Sale::where('type', 'supplier')->where('customer', 'LIKE', '%peter%')->get();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to retrieve `suppliers` only if there are not `retailers`?, or any of the both as long as they meet the `LIKE` condition?.

Comment: $data = Sale::where('customer', 'LIKE', '%peter%')
                        ->where(function($query) {
                            $query->orWhere('type', 'retailer');
                            $query->orWhere('type', 'supplier');
                        })->get();

Comment: @JuanEizmendi  yes, i want to retrieve `suppliers` only if not `retailers`. and also same want retrieve `retailers` only, if both tables also have the customer